# Override truth or ! operator in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

How do I override the truth-value of my class instance, or its ! operator?

For example (simplified names/usage):

```
MyClass variable = [MyClass alloc] initWithValue: nil];
```

...

```
if (!variable) { NSLog(@"'Not variable value' works"); }
```

I've searched for two possible solutions but couldn't find anything useful. In some languages i would overload an isTrue, asBool, etc function; or override the unary *!* operator **FOR THAT CLASS** (not the main NOT operator.

My initial reaction to this problem was: *You don't need to in Objective-C, you're going at it wrong.* While true, I have lost over hours debugging some code that had the above `(!variable)` **instead of**

```
if (!variable.value) { NSLog(@"'Not variable value' works"); }
```

MyClass has property value among many others, which you can set or not. It defines whether or not you do something so it is common to need `if (!variable.value){ NSLog(@"Warning, value not set"); }`

So I want to overload the ! or isTrue function to check whether or not `variable.value` is set instead of merely checking if `variable` is linked to an address. This would make my code more readable and make my class more useable.

To be clear, in this example, `variable` points to an alloc-init'ed object, where `variable.value = nil` for example.

For example this can be done in python by overloading __ nonzero __.

As a side question that would answer this question: How does the truth value of an object work in Objective-C?

Comment: You cannot override operators in Objective-C (at least not without having to do unnatural acts).

Comment: (Understand that `!pointerVariable` is defined by the C language to test whether the pointer in nil.  Changing that would break lots of things.)

Comment: I want to change it for my class, not in general, like in C++.

Comment: Well, what you want and what you can do are two different things.

Comment: I understand your issue -- I had a bug that eluded me for several days that was due to `if (somePtr)` when it should have been `if (somePtr.boolValue)`.  But there is neither a facility to diagnose this bug nor a way to "finesse" it -- you just have to work harder to avoid writing in bugs.

Comment: Thanks, perhaps i'll add a function similar to [somePtr noValue]. boolValue is basically what I'm actually doing here, and now i see why it can be bad, because we just forget to code it and check the pointer directly. If anyone knows why this question should be -1, please let me know, it seemed like a valid question

Comment: The question is something that anyone programming Objective-C should not need to ask.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61864/discussion-between-pierre-francoys-brousseau-and-hot-licks).

Comment: @Pierre-FrancoysBrousseau: I think this is a valid question. The downvote seems ungenerous. Re: your additions to the question, what you're proposing might make sense in Python or elsewhere, but would be wildly non-idiomatic in C or ObjC. Even if you could coerce such a behavior, other programmers are trained to see `if (!foo)..` as meaning something very specific around pointer validity.

Comment: @Pierre-FrancoysBrousseau: The "truth value of an object" is simple: it's whether the pointer to it is valid, meaning it's non-nil. (You could willfully assign a garbage value to a pointer and it would also be non-nil, and thus "valid" for this sort of boolean check.) In general, this means it points to a live object that's been alloc/init-ed. This is useful because you can set pointers to nil as a sentinel meaning "I haven't created one of these yet", etc. This does mean though that any higher-order semantic "validity" must be checked by other means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override these things in ObjC. ObjC behaves just like C in this regard-- object references are pointers, either valid or `nil`-- a `nil` value evaluates to `NO` in a boolean expression and any non-nil value will appear as `YES`.

---

The canonical check for "is this thing an invalid pointer" is `if (!thing) { ... }`.
If you are always doing this:

```
if (!variable.value) ...
```

then perhaps `variable` is of type `NSNumber` or some object container for a primitive? It's hard to tell without context what pattern you're using and whether there's a better idiom for this.

Comment: variable is of type MyClass, which has .value property (or say .istrue) . 

I feared this was a pure C operator... But can't you overload like in C++?

Comment: @Pierre-FrancoysBrousseau: You may want to edit your question to say even more. What is the semantic you require for the `.istrue`? Normally an object isn't generally "true" or not; the existence of the object is enough to indicate its presence in the world.

Answer (score 1):

An object in Objective-C has the same meaning in a boolean expression as a pointer in C, because it is a C pointer. If the pointer is `NULL` -- or `nil` for an object -- then it's false; otherwise it's true.

You can't override operators in Objective-C.

This said, `!variable.value` does indeed test whether `value` is `nil` (assuming that `value` has an object type) -- the dot operator resolves to a message send `[variable value]` whose return value is then negated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Ben Answered a few seconds before you so i'll accept his.